# написать запрос на добавление массива в бд одним запросом

Tags: php

Мне нужно правильно написать запрос на добавление массива из инпутов одним запросом. В текущем запросе ошибка.

```php
<?php

require_once '../vendor/connect.php';


for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); ++$i) {
    $name = $name[$i];
    $price = $price[$i];
    $quantity = $quantity[$i];


    

$q = "INSERT INTO `zakaz` (`name`, `price`, `quantity`) VALUES ('$name', '$price', '$quantity')";


var_dump($_POST);
mysqli_query($connect, $q);



}





?>
```

```html
 <input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="${name}">
                    <input class="js-cart-input-quantity" type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="${quantity}">
                    <input class="js-cart-input-price" type="hidden" name="price[]" value="${price * quantity}">
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `zakaz` (
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136448/discussion-on-question-by-daniil--------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работать всегда лучше с подготовленными данными. Если технические ограничения не позволяют получить данные в удобном виде, то лучше пересобрать их до того как начинать манипуляции с ними.

Сейчас у вас есть три массива $names, $prices, $quantities, но нужен один $orders ($zakazes, если так удобнее :-).

```
$orders = array_map(
    fn($name, $price, $quantity) => ['name' => $name, 'price' => $price, 'quantity' => $quantity],
    $names,
    $prices,
    $quantities
);
var_dump($orders); // посмотрите что получилось
```

Теперь можно заняться запросом в бд. Insert может принимать несколько пачек значений и вставлять несколько строк. Сперва надо написать общую часть запроса.

```
$sql = 'insert into `zakaz` (`name`, `price`, `quantity`) values ';
```

Остаётся только для каждого $order из $orders добавить к запросу `($order['name'], $order['price'], $order['quantity'])`. Это просто. Но прежде чем написать код, вам стоит узнать про [SQL-инъекции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Чтообы предотвратить инъекции, вы можете использовать экранирование с помощью [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (обратите внимание на предостережение насчёт кодировки) или [подготовленные запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Второй вариант сложнее, я не буду разбирать его тут, но обязательно изучите эту тему самостоятельно.

```
$sqlValues = [];
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $sqlValues[] = '('
        . implode(', ', array_map(fn($val) => "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $val) . "'", $order))
        . ')';
    
}
$sql .= implode(', ', $sqlValues);
var_dump($sql); // посмотрите что получилось
```

Теперь можно выполнить получившийся запрос.

Этот пример только демонстрирует общую идею. Не копируйте его в свой код. Он должен быть отправной точкой для ваших самостоятельных изысканий. Например, тут я не валидирую входящие данные, рассматриваю цену и количество как строки, не обрабатываю возможные ошибки.

Comment: "var_dump($orders); // посмотрите что получилось" --- NULL

Comment: @Daniil у вас эти массивы называются в единственном числе, без s на конце

Comment: Действительно..

Comment: "VM10:6772 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated." == что могло бы это значить, в результате запроса?  Это связано с экранированием?

Comment: @Daniil вероятно что-то связанное с VSCode. Гугланите "JS module files deprecated", используйте переводчик, чтобы разобраться в обсуждениях на английском. К php и к вашему первоначальному вопросу это отношения вообще не имеет.

Comment: Данная штука выходит в консольке браузера, и каким-то образом мешает запросу

Comment: Помимо этого есть и такая ошибка "chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"

Comment: @Daniil видимо пора переходить на Firefox :-) Но вы можете задать вопрос насчёт этой ошибки в отдельном вопросе на stackoverflow, там его скорее увидят, чем тут в комментариях

Comment: Меня мучают сомнения что эти ошибки связаны как-то с запросом, ведь массив так и не дошел до БД :(

Comment: @Daniil Я вам об этом и пытался выше донести. Забудьте пока про запросы. Первоочередная задача - вывести полученные данные через `var_dump($_POST)`. Больше ничего в скрипте, на этом этапе, не должно быть.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Вы имеете ввиду вот это? $name = $_POST['name']; и т.д.